# Trying to show only one form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic

im currently doing a MERN app and i have a litle issue...

What i'm doing is creating an app where you can create rooms, and in those rooms you can create whhat you will do in your day, its literally like a TODO app but more complex ( i wanted to give you a short background about my app so you can understand more )

The problem is that, i have a botton, and when you click that button a form it's going to appear instead of the buttons, but, if i have 2 rooms, both rooms are going to show the form, and i only need one room ( the one i clicked ) to show the room

Let me show you the logic i tried to do...

```
const Room = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile"));

  const [Todo, setTodo] = useState(false);
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

  // Asking For The Data

  const rooms = useSelector(state =>
    state.rooms.filter(
      r => r.name === user?.result?.name || r.creator === user?.result?._id
    )
  );

  const handleShow = id => {
    console.log(id);
    const truthy = rooms.find(identificator => identificator._id === id);
    console.log(truthy._id);
    if (truthy._id === id) {
      setShowForm(true);
    } else {
      setShowForm(false);
    }
  };

  if (user?.result) {
    return (
      <>
        {/* Todo Window */}

        {Todo && <ToDo setTodo={setTodo} />}

        {/*  */}

        <MainBackground>
          <Container>
            {/* Showing The Rooms */}

            {rooms.map(room => {
              return (
                <Rooms key={room._id}>
                  <section>
                    <User>
                      <CreatedTime>
                        {user?.result?.name} <br />
                        <span>{moment(room.createdAt).fromNow()}</span>
                      </CreatedTime>
                      <span
                        style={{ cursor: "pointer", marginRight: "1rem" }}
                        onClick={() => setTodo(true)}
                      >
                        <OpenItUp />
                      </span>
                    </User>

                    <RoomStuff>
                      <h2>{room.room}</h2>
                    </RoomStuff>

                    {/* Buttons And The Form To Create Your Shit */}

                    <RoomsButtons>
                      {!showForm ? (
                        <>
                          <span>
                            <RoomsButtonEdit
                              onClick={() => handleShow(room._id)}
                            />
                          </span>
                          <span
                            onClick={() => dispatch(deletingRooms(room._id))}
                          >
                            <RoomsButtonDelete />
                          </span>
                        </>
                      ) : (
                        /* Form */

                        <FormTodo setShowForm={setShowForm} />
                      )}
                    </RoomsButtons>
                  </section>
                </Rooms>
              );
            })}
```

When you click RoomsButtonEdit, in the onclick function ( handleShow ) , i'm passing the id of the room, then i compare that id with the actual room, if the id matches, setShowForm(true) (it means that the form will appear instead of the buttons), but if it doesn't match, the form can not appear

The problem is that, when i click, bot forms appear...

Here's the photo of the rooms

[image]

[image]

Please help me with this issue, if you can help me through this, you're amazing !

Thank for your time comunnity !

Answer (score 0):

here you are finding the room with the property **_id** equal to **id**

```
const truthy = rooms.find(identificator => identificator._id === id);
```

With this room that you found (truthy) you are testing if truthy._id is equal to id
which will always be true because this id is what you used to filter the rooms array

```
if (truthy._id === id)
```

Comment: Yeah, i was mad and i tried that, i know it's a noobie thing

Do you know a way to get me out of this issue?